# Finding commuting matrices

Tags: matrices

Is there a procedure for finding all matrices which commute with two given square and complex matrices?

For example, given two elements $A,B \in$ $\mathfrak{su}(4)$ is it possible to find all elements which commute with both $A$ and $B$ individually.

Comment: I think the elements that commute with both $A$ and $B$ are those whose all eigenspaces corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues lie in an intersection of an eigenspace of $A$ and one of $B$. (And if all such intersections are trivial, only the zero matrix commutes with both.)

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of solving a system of linear equations?

Comment: I'm also interested in any short cut to knowing that such a matrix exists, without particularly needing to find it explicitly.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That can't be right, since certainly scalar multiples of the identity commute with both $A$ and $B$.  The feeling I have is rather that the eigenspaces of a matrix commuting with $A$ and $B$ should be big.  Also, whether an eigenvalue is zero or not shouldn't matter, since $M$ will commute with $A$ and $B$ iff $\lambda I + M$ does.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  As Noah mentions, at a not too high-level the answer is the solution of the linear system $AH=HA$,  $BH=HB$.  You could also answer the question at the level of canonical forms.  More generally, two matrices commute if and only if they can be expressed as polynomials in some common matrix.  I'm not sure if any of these are very useful to you.  But you have not given us enough information to know what kind of answer you want.

Comment: I'm after two things. A) a test which determines if there exists a matrix commuting with two given matrices. B) an algorithm, akin to gram Schmidt, for finding all such matrices in terms of the original ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generically (e.g., if one of the matrices has distinct eigenvalues, or more generally, is non-derogatory; for two commuting matrices, the conditions are even weaker), the centralizer of a single matrix just consists of the polynomials in that matrix. So if you pick a pair of commuting matrices at random, the polynomials in them will almost always suffice.

But if you select a random pair of matrices (not commuting), generically they will generate the entire matrix algebra, and so the centralizer will consist of the scalar matrices.

Of course, if you're being picky, you have to look at common invariant subspaces, a nuisance.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Do you have a reference for the statement: 'the centralizer of a single matrix just consists of the polynomials in that matrix'?

Comment: Remember, I said what amounts to *almost* all matrices are non-derogatory, not all matrices. If the matrix is non-derogatory (that is, it admits a cyclic vector; equivalently, there is only one Jordan block per eigenvalue), just look at the regular representation, sending the matrix to the multiplication by it, acting  on the vector space it spans (which by non-derogatoriness, will be the original $n$-dimensional vector space on which all the original matrices are acting), and this extends to an algebra embedding, etc. (This is a standard argument.)

Comment: Ah, I actually misread your sentence there. My mistake. Could have a reference for the fact which is in fact a fact and not what I said!

Answer (score 5):

I am answering the two questions (A) and (B) in the OP's comment. The answer is really already contained in @RyanBudney's comment: this is a linear system ($AH = HA, BH = HB,$) so you are asking if a linear system has a solution, and if yes, describe all the solutions. The short answer to both questions is "row reduction".

**Addendum** A slightly fancier way of putting the above: you are looking for the intersection of kernels of $A\otimes I - I \otimes A$ and $B\otimes I - I \otimes B.$

Answer (score 3):

EDIT.  Prop.: If there is a not scalar matrix $H$ s.t. $AH=HA,BH=HB$ then $A,B$ have a non-trivial common invariant subspace.

Proof.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by $A,B$; since $H$ commute with the elements of $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A}$ is not whole $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. According to the Burnside's theorem, $A,B$ have a non trivial common invariant subspace.

As Clement writes below, the converse is false. Moreover, it is easier to solve the system $\{AH=HA,BH=HB\}$ rather than finding the common invariant spaces of $A,B$ of dimension $k\in (o,n)$. For those who are interested in this problem, one reference is

Tsatsomeros, "A criterion for the existence of common invariant subspaces of matrices". http://www.sci.wsu.edu/math/faculty/tsat/files/t3.pdf

If $k=1$, then it is easy; use the Shemesh criterion (Theorem 3.1).

If $k>1$, then we may assume that $A,B$ are invertible and use Corollary 2.3. Unfortunately, using the previous method can be challenging; in particular, when $k$ increases, the numerical complexity exponentially grows.

Comment: The converse implication does not work. For the idempotent $H$ to commute with $A$ and $B$ you would need $G$ to be an invariant subspace for both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The matrices $E_{1,1}$ and $E_{1,2}$ of $M_2(C)$ have a common (non-trivial) invariant subspace but only scalar matrices commute with both of them.

Comment: I note that somebody downvoted my edit without giving name or explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You might ask whether there is an idempotent matrix $E$ which commutes with both $A$ and $B$. If there is ( with $0 \neq E \neq I$), then you can reduce the question to lower dimension ( the underlying space is the direct sum of the $1$-eigenspace of $E$ and the $0$-eigenspace of $E$, and these are both invariant under $A$ and $B$). If there is no such idempotent matirx $E$, then the matrices which commute with both $A$ and $B$ form a local ring, and, in particular, since you are working with complex matrices, any matrix which commutes with both $A$ and $B$ has just one eigenvalue.

Comment: Is there any way that avoids writing out the matrices in coordinates. We can find a vector orthogonal to a given one in $R^3$ using the cross product. Is there anything similar to do here? For example, a matrix I can express in terms of $A,B$ only and not their elements.